# How to download playlist to mp3 format with youtube-dl?

Tags: command-line, downloads, youtube, youtube-dl, playlists

I'm trying to download some videos in mp3 format. It's a playlist. How do I download the whole playlist using one command?

Comment: To get the URL for a mix, right click on a song in the mix in the right column. "Copy link location" will give a url ending with `&index=7`. This is the kind of link which will cause `[youtube:playlist] Downloading playlist ...`.

Answer (score 246):

Both parts of this question (downloading in mp3 *and* downloading a playlist) are supported by `youtube-dl`:

```
youtube-dl --extract-audio --audio-format mp3 -o "%(title)s.%(ext)s" <url to playlist>
```

Some notes from me and the comments:

- Older versions of `youtube-dl` struggle with modern playlists. You might need to [replace the repo version with the latest](https://askubuntu.com/q/536404/).
- **cmo**: You can ignore missing ("unavailable in your country", or removed) videos with an `-i` flag.
- **frans**: If your playlist isn't working and the URL contains a `v=<ID>` element, remove it so there's just the `?list=...` item in the querystring.

Comment: nope it only downloaded the first video

Comment: @user267628 I've tested this with a playlist URL and it works for me. I had to upgrade `youtube-dl` (see link at the end) but it sounds like your problem is you're not giving it a playlist URL.

Comment: it works perfectly for me

Comment: Sometimes you copy s.th. like `https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=<VIDEO_ID>&list=<LIST_ID>`. I had to remove the `v=<ID>` part from the URL.

Comment: how would i get the <url to playlist> via commandline? I'd like to use the ytsearch feature

Comment: works perfectly, after updating youtube-dl (i.e. after executing `youtube-dl -U`).  very elegant answer

Comment: I recommend you include the `-i` argument in the command.  it will skip any videos in the playlist that have been removed from youtube

Comment: @cmo thanks for this tip. Works also to skip blocked  content based on country.

Comment: Thanks for that! @frans thanks you too the tip! Worked fine after removing the v=ID part from the URL :)

Comment: https://github.com/rg3/youtube-dl/issues/698#issuecomment-212984683 to skip errors

Comment: I wanted the padded track numbers as a prefix so I changed this to `youtube-dl --extract-audio --audio-format mp3 -o "%(autonumber)02d-%(title)s.%(ext)s" <url to playlist>` (added `%(autonumber)02d-`)

Answer (score 52):

Note:- Old version of youtube-dl is not able to download play-list. first you know what is your youtube-dl version. To check version of Youtube-dl use command

```
youtube-dl --version
```

version 2014.02.17 and older version not able to download play-list.
If you use older version then update it by

```
sudo youtube-dl -U
```

after successful update use command

```
youtube-dl -cit https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLttJ4RON7sleuL8wDpxbKHbSJ7BH4vvCk
```

Also you can create URL list in a simple text file and use following command.

```
 youtube-dl -cit -a file_name_in_which_you_paste_URL_list
```

**For MP3 format** Audio can saved. But audio saves as .m4a format on my machine.

```
youtube-dl -cit --extract-audio --audio-format mp3 https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLttJ4RON7sleuL8wDpxbKHbSJ7BH4vvCk
```

**NOTE :-** If you install youtube-dl from Ubuntu software center. You can't update it from terminal.

Go Software center and update from it. 
I test this commands on Wine because my youtube-dl also old. And I am unable to Update it. 
If you can update your youtube-dl you can download play-list by using above commands.
 I hope it helps...[image: Youtube-dl on WINE]

Comment: Download Youtube-dl.exe nad try youtube-dl on WINE. If you unable to Update it.

Comment: [see also](http://askubuntu.com/questions/631832/how-to-uninstall-youtube-dl-by-using-terminal/631939#631939)

Comment: [python base installation](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/207909/how-can-i-install-youtube-dl-on-boss-linux)

Comment: Don't use the Windows version in Wine, just install it with PIP (the Python package manager). You may need to install PIP (`sudo apt install pip3`), but then `sudo pip3 install youtube-dl` to install, and `sudo pip3 install youtube-dl --upgrade` to get the latest version. I recommend upgrading every time before you use youtube-dl. Oh, and yes, use the Python 3 PIP instead of Python 2.

Comment: Easier to just get the script (using `curl` and `chmod` as suggested [here](https://rg3.github.io/youtube-dl/download.html)) than use a package manager (pip, apt etc)

Comment: Wilf, you get the latest version too, which you need to build sometimes depending on distro. but chmod +x yes

Comment: Damn just noticed this command only downloads the 51st songs in a playlist due to well youtube.... just so you are aware, must make some workaround of sorts here

Answer (score 12):

There are a lot of instructions you can find using your favorite search engine. E.g.:

- [www.xmodulu.com/...](http://xmodulo.com/how-to-download-youtube-playlist-in-linux.html)

For [this Playlist](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLYH8WvNV1YEnNVnJb5ZXxDCE2HDAVVo4M)  it would be: `youtube-dl -t https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLYH8WvNV1YEnNVnJb5ZXxDCE2HDAVVo4M`

I hope I could help you!

Comment: And you should add the parameters by @Oli, too. `youtube-dl -t --extract-audio --audio-format mp3 https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLYH8WvNV1YEnNVnJb5ZXxDCE2HDAVVo4M`

Comment: nope only one song loads

Comment: works for me (version 2015.02.28)

Answer (score 6):

If you installed using pip, run the following to update:

```
 sudo pip install youtube-dl --upgrade
```

Enjoy...

Comment: Sometimes you need the updated source, just git it and compile it.

Answer (score 4):

an additon to [Oli](https://askubuntu.com/users/449/oli) 's answer. If you have the playlist (in separate lines) with all URLs in it in a text file  to download:

```
youtube-dl --extract-audio --audio-format mp3 --batch-file="/full/path/to/playlist"
```

Answer (score 4):

All good answers here, but let me save everyone the pain of issues when trying to download playlists.

First, you can't just download things as fast as you want.  Youtube will ban your IP for awhile if you do this.

Also some playlist videos are sometimes "private" or broken, or deleted.

To avoid all these problems do this.

```
youtube-dl --sleep-interval 30  -i -f 251 URL_HERE
```

Just to add some extra clarity.  You do not have to sue the -f tag with a number.  You can use a specific file extension that is supported.

```
youtube-dl --sleep-interval 30  -i -f mp3 URL_HERE
```

youtube dl will always try to download the best version.

See documentation for more information - https://github.com/ytdl-org/youtube-dl/blob/master/README.md#format-selection

Comment: Thanks for this suggestion. What does the `251` stand for? Is this a particular format?

Comment: It is the format type you want to use.  You don't have to use the cryptic numbers.  If you just want the best and do not care about the format then you can use nothing.  It will automatically download the best format it can get, but if you specifically want audio you can target a certain type.

https://github.com/ytdl-org/youtube-dl/blob/master/README.md#format-selection

Comment: Thanks, that link says "youtube-dl uses -f bestvideo+bestaudio/best as the default format selection ", I guess it makes sens to use `-f 'worstvideo,bestaudio'` to download sound files.

Answer (score 3):

Are you **really** sure you want MP3? A lot of devices nowadays can play AAC and some can even play Opus.

If you want to retain highest quality (Opus 160 kbps) and your player supports Opus codec it's better to use:

```
youtube-dl -f 251 (Playlist URL)
```

But if your player only supports AAC (as most entry-level TVs in 2018):

```
youtube-dl -f 140 (Playlist URL)
```

If you use MP3 you'll get degraded quality as reencoding (from already reencoded audio by YouTube) will be required.