# How to uninstall/install youtube-dl by using terminal

Tags: command-line, apt, update-manager, ppa, youtube-dl

I installed [YouTube-dl](https://youtube-dl.org/) through Ubuntu Software Center, but now mine isn't working. So I can not able to Update and Install youtube-dl.  I tried this:

```
$ sudo add-apt-repository ppa:nilarimogard/webupd8
$ sudo apt-get update
$ sudo apt-get install youtube-dl
```

then following errors occurs......

```
$ youtube-dl --version
2014.02.17
$ sudo add-apt-repository ppa:nilarimogard/webupd8
[sudo] password for madhavnikam: 
 The main Web Upd8 PPA maintained by: http://www.webupd8.org/

To add this PPA, simply paste this in a terminal:
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:nilarimogard/webupd8

Packages in this PPA: audacious, ap-hotspot, awn-applet-radio, awn-applet-wm, calise, cmus, dockbarx, dockbarx-themes-extra, dropbox-share, emerald, exaile, fbmessenger, gnome-subtitles, gnome-window-applets, grsync, grive, gthumb, launchpad-getkeys, mc, mdm (Mint Display Manager), minitunes, minitube, musique, notifyosdconfig, nautilus-columns, powertop, ppa-purge, rosa-media-player, fixed pulseaudio-equalizer, subtitleeditor, syncwall, umplayer, unity-reboot, wimlib, youtube-dl, xfce4-dockbarx-plugin, xournal, yad and others. Almost all packages are updated to their latest version.

For other (specialized) PPAs we maintain, see: https://launchpad.net/~webupd8team
 More info: https://launchpad.net/~nilarimogard/+archive/ubuntu/webupd8
Press [ENTER] to continue or ctrl-c to cancel adding it

gpg: keyring `/tmp/tmpl8q4d9le/secring.gpg' created
gpg: keyring `/tmp/tmpl8q4d9le/pubring.gpg' created
gpg: requesting key 4C9D234C from hkp server keyserver.ubuntu.com
gpg: /tmp/tmpl8q4d9le/trustdb.gpg: trustdb created
gpg: key 4C9D234C: public key "Launchpad webupd8" imported
gpg: Total number processed: 1
gpg:               imported: 1  (RSA: 1)
OK
$ sudo apt-get update
Ign http://in.archive.ubuntu.com trusty InRelease                              
[...]
Ign http://in.archive.ubuntu.com trusty/universe Translation-en_IN
Fetched 1,784 kB in 1min 29s (20.0 kB/s)
Reading package lists... Error!
E: Encountered a section with no Package: header
E: Problem with MergeList /var/lib/apt/lists/in.archive.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_trusty_main_i18n_Translation-en
E: The package lists or status file could not be parsed or opened.
$ sudo apt-get install youtube-dl
Reading package lists... Error!
E: Encountered a section with no Package: header
E: Problem with MergeList /var/lib/apt/lists/in.archive.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_trusty_main_i18n_Translation-en
E: The package lists or status file could not be parsed or opened.

$ youtube-dl -U
It looks like you installed youtube-dl with a package manager, pip, setup.py or a tarball. Please use that to update.
```

How can I uninstall and install Youtube-dl by using terminal only?

Comment: First fix the error you are encountering using [this post](http://askubuntu.com/a/30199/178596). What version of youtube-dl are you currently using (you can use `youtube-dl --version` for that)?

Comment: @Wilf thanks it working with no errors. I try below commands 
sudo rm /var/lib/apt/lists/* -vf
sudo apt-get update
 what should do next?

Comment: error occur al last W: Failed to fetch http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/trusty-updates/main/i18n/Translation-en  Hash Sum mismatch

Comment: W: Failed to fetch http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/trusty-updates/universe/i18n/Translation-en  Hash Sum mismatch

E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.

Comment: You can use the [edit] button to add information to your question.... are you connected to the internet via a proxy? `/var/lib/apt/lists/` should be empty after running the first command

Comment: @Wilf am not use proxy. And i am not understand what should i edit on my question can you help me or suggest actual edit.

Comment: You can edit in the output you put in the comments, because its difficult to read in the comments :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/24428/discussion-between-madhav-nikam-and-wilf).

Comment: @Wilf I try to edit comments but i am unable now.Edit option is disable now, may older comment. Sorry for that. But i remember you suggestion for next time.  Thank You.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I solve the problem by using these commands:

1. `sudo apt-get remove youtube-dl`

   [image: remove youtube-dl]

   After that:
2. `sudo apt-get install youtube-dl`

   [image: install youtube-dl]
3. Downloading play-list...

   ```
   youtube-dl -cit --extract-audio --audio-format mp3 https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLttJ4RON7sleuL8wDpxbKHbSJ7BH4vvCk
   ```

   [image: downloading playlist by Youtube-dl]

Done.

Answer (score 7):

Try `pip` command to upgrade `youtube-dl`

```
sudo pip install --upgrade youtube-dl
```

If you get this message:

```
sudo: pip: command not found
```

Then first install `pip`:

```
sudo apt-get install python-setuptools
sudo easy_install pip
sudo pip install --upgrade youtube-dl
```

Comment: Update 2022: use this `sudo apt-get install python3-pip` not this `sudo easy_install pip`

Answer (score 3):

It would be easier to use --reinstall

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall youtube-dl
```

then use it:

```
 youtube-dl -cit --extract-audio --audio-format mp3 https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLttJ4RON7sleuL8wDpxbKHbSJ7BH4vvCk
```

Comment: So why the downvote?

Answer (score 1):

Why you don't use [the recommended official way to install youtube-dl](https://rg3.github.io/youtube-dl/download.html)? Very useful since **very often** you will need to update it (`sudo youtube-dl -U`) to bleeding edge stable version to keep it working:

```
sudo wget https://yt-dl.org/downloads/latest/youtube-dl -O /usr/local/bin/youtube-dl

sudo chmod a+rx /usr/local/bin/youtube-dl
```

And [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/878922/349837) you'll find a bash script I made for batch downloading getting track names from a text file.