# How can I download an entire playlist from youtube even it exceeds 25 videos?

Tags: 14.04, downloads, youtube, playlists

I know it may seem a duplicate question but I'm a very new user of ubuntu and those old methods I searched didn't work for me

What I'm looking for is a guaranteed **updated** way with steps showing me how to download full playlists from `youtube`.
I have tried many ways using many applications but all are need to be activated to download playlists with more than 25 videos
Another way is the **Terminal** way which I completely don't understand so you'll be doing me a big favor of showing me how the whole story goes

**The terminal way :** [Problems downloading playlist using youtube-dl](https://askubuntu.com/questions/536404/problems-downloading-playlist-using-youtube-dl)

Thanks in advance

Comment: What is this terminal way you mention ? That would be the preferred method here, link it and I will try to interpret it for you. Also what browser are you using ?

Comment: edited the question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Based on the answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/536404/problems-downloading-playlist-using-youtube-dl) you linked, here are clear instructions on using `youtube-dl`

First remove any installed version

```
 sudo apt-get purge youtube-dl
```

If you downloaded from the link run

```
sudo rm /usr/local/bin/youtube-dl
```

Now download the latest file to /usr/local/bin (newer one than the one in the link)

```
sudo wget https://yt-dl.org/downloads/2015.11.27.1/youtube-dl -O /usr/local/bin/youtube-dl
```

Now give it permissions

```
sudo chmod a+rx /usr/local/bin/youtube-dl
```

Here is a test command to download from a nice Linux based channel, [Linux Scoop](https://www.youtube.com/user/linuxscoop/featured) (get the url of the page you want to download), and run `youtube-dl` followed by the page

```
youtube-dl https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLKopOf5__2tjZ3oHnreRYjxGW_7yXV0OS
```

You can check for updates to this non repository version by running

```
youtube-dl -U
```

To see a list of all commands in the terminal, you can run

```
youtube-dl --help
```

For more detailed documentation [go here](https://github.com/rg3/youtube-dl/blob/master/README.md#options).

Tested on 14.04.

Comment: Thank you very much sir you saved my day I wish I can rate it up .. but if I'm not bothering you can you link me the youtube-dl settings commands up ?